# htaccess redirectaion not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

As part of a migration I need to redirect sections of a site.

The below RedirectMatch is working, but the query string is being carried across.
I have tried using a "?" in various ways to remove the original query string, but have been unable to get it to work.

Current RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/store/match.*$ http://shop.domain.com/new-directory/
```

The above RedirectMatch turns this:

```
domain.com/store/match-something-something-c-536.html?osCsid=123456…
```

Into this:

```
shop.domain.com/new-directory/?cPath=536&osCsid=123456...
```

But I want:

```
shop.domain.com/new-directory/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^store/match http://shop.domain.com/new-directory/? [R=301,L,NC]
```